# Filling-in word form from access vba in readonly mode does not work in O365

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an Access database with VBA for filling-in a word document in readonly mode. It does work properly in Office 2016 but does not work in O365. In Office 365 the fields remain empty whereas in Office 2016 the data is populated in the fields correctly.

The Word document has to be opened in readonly mode so that the original document cannot be changed.

Does anyone knows this issue or did I miss something?

Here es an example, how I open the word document:

```
Sub FillIn()
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim Doc As Word.Document

Set WordApp = New Word.Application
WordApp.Visible = True

Set Doc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\myWordTemplate.docx", ReadOnly:=True)
With Doc
    .FormFields("Firstname").Result = Me.Firstname
    .FormFields("Lastname").Result = Me.Lastname
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Does it work fine when it's not in Read Only mode?

Comment: @braX Yes, when `ReadOnly:=False` then it works in both versions. But this is not a solution for me.

Comment: Then try it using `.Add` instead, and use the template argument. (without using ReadOnly)

Comment: @braX Thanks for the alternative solution. With .Add it works, however the filepath shown in the save as dialog is not the path of the file which is added. It shows instead the default word saving-path. So the user has to choose the right path every time.

Comment: Ok the path is now a minor problem. The big problem with .Add is, that the user can change the content of the generated document which should not be allowed.
So I need a solution like ReadOnly mode which should work in every Office version.
Thanks for any further help.

Comment: You can use `Protect` instead of read only. Your code would unprotect it only to make those changes and then re-protect it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.protect

Comment: Protection is a good idea. Thanks for that.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned it first... It can be toggled so code can edit it, but "read only" mode is different.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I unprotect the document and after the form is filled out it gets protected. As a workaround and very near to the solution it works. However I'm wondering why the .Open method does not work in O365. If someone has any ideas about it, I appreciate your help. Thank you once again.

Comment: Did you try it with the `.Open` method but without the `ReadOnly` option?

Comment: Yes I did try .Open. without ReadOnly and it works. However the user can override the original file what he/she is not supposed to do.

Comment: My point is that `Protect` will work the same regardless of whether you use `.Open` or `.Add` - Just don't use `ReadOnly`

Comment: ChDir does not work. I posted a new question on that topic [here]
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73743321/vba-chdrive-chdir-does-not-work-if-the-file-is-saved)

Comment: Yes, Protect works with .Open and .Add alike. But when I set `ReadOnly:=False` then the original document can be overwritten by the user in the case of .Open if he presses Ctrl+S or say save. And that is not my goal.